# How would you develop a function for API response parsing using TDD?

Tags: python, tdd

I just read *"Test Driven Development: By Example"* by Kent Beck, and am trying to apply it on my current project.

Given an API response I need to extract information from it. API response is a JSON array:

```json
[
 {"1789484079": "event1", "1531059415": "event2"},
 {},
 {},
 {"1234256612": "event3"}
]
```

Each object in that array may have multiple keys, each key is a timestamp. Object may be empty.

The task is to find a most recent "event" according to given timestamp. For example:

- if given timestamp is 1889484079 "event1" shall be returned;
- if given timestamp is 1689484079 an "event2" is a right choice.

So, following the book's guidance, a test and a naive implementation which returns a constant:

```py
def parse_response(response, timestamp):
    return "event1"


def test_api_response_parsing_returns_correct_events():
    response = [{1789484079: "event1", 1531059415: "event2"}]
    timestamp = 1889484079
    assert parse_response(response, timestamp) == "event1"
```

Now I need to make the test fail, so I have room for improvements.

```py
def test_api_response_parsing_returns_correct_events():
    response = [{1789484079: "event1", 1531059415: "event2"}]
    timestamp = 1889484079
    assert parse_response(response, timestamp) == "event1"
    timestamp = 1689484079
    assert parse_response(response, timestamp) == "event2"
```

What could the next step have been if we want to keep moving by little steps, as Kent Beck suggests in his book?

Introduce 2 more constants?

```
def parse_response(response, timestamp):
    if timestamp == 1889484079:
        return "event1"
    else:
        return "event2"
```

This starts to seem like duplication, which we must get rid of. And how would we do it? My thought for the next step is that we have timestamps in `response`, so in order to remove the duplication we have to iterate over response while checking timestamps according to rules which function have to follow, but isn't it a big leap and not a small step?

How would you develop this function if you were following TDD principles?

Comment: You can just use the `response` parameter now. If you make the implementation just: `return response[0][timestamp]`. This will just make both tests pass and you can start to think about what the next feature is that you want to test into being.

Comment: Hi @quamrana! Unfortunately it will fail with "KeyError" exception, passed timestamp is not necessary in the `response`, it is used as parameter which we should consider when searching for the correct event, timestamps greater than passed shall be ignored

Comment: Ok, I see what's happening. So why, for the first test do you pass in `timestamp = 1889484079` and expect to receive `event1` back when that timestamp is not in the `response` parameter?

Comment: That's because your example is already slightly too complex. The simplest test would be `[{"0": "event1"}]` -> `"event1"`: if there's only one event, it's always the most recent. Then `[{"0": "event1", "1": "event2"}]` -> `"event2"`: if there are multiple events, take the last one. Then depending on your context and needs you might think e.g. "what if the timestamp is _before_ the last event?" or "what if there's more than one object in the array?" for the next step (keep your examples consistent with real structure - will the latest event always in the last object in the array, for example?)

Comment: @Javed - this isn't really the right sort of question for stack overflow; there's no single "authoritative" answer.  You should be looking for audiences expecting to have a discussion - so maybe the old Test Driven Development mailing list: https://groups.io/g/testdrivendevelopment or a slack channel, maybe https://slack.softwarecrafters.org/ or https://wedotdd.com/ (slack invite link at bottom of page).

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason, Hi! Think you're right and it's more or less about a discussion, but couldn't find a better place to start it, thank you for the links!:)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for your advice on simplest test, it was very helpful! I was able to progress. Seems like I missed that part of the book. Strange, now it looks to me like a key concept! Thanks again :^)